# Position of "is"

Tags: grammaticality

Which of these sentences is correct and has *is* in the correct position?

> It is not important how but when the change is brought.

or

> It is not important how but when is the change brought.

Answer (score 2):

Clauses headed by  *Wh-* subordinators like *when*, *how*, *who*, and the like usually keep the subject and verb in the ordinary order:

> ... how [<sup>SUBJECT</sup> the change] [<sup>VERB</sup> is brought] ... .

Inversion - placing the auxiliary verb (or a form of *DO*, if there is no auxiliary present) **before** the subject - occurs only in questions:

> How [<sup>AuxVERB</sup> **is**] [<sup>SUBJECT</sup> the change] [<sup>LexVERB</sup> brought] **?**

Consequently, the proper form for your sentence, which is an assertion not a question, is your first version:

> It is not important how but when the change is brought.